# How to track user's movements from one point to another without gps? (mobile devices)

Tags: android, ios, windows-phone-8, navigation, gps

I want to create application which will navigate user at the shopping mall. So, I'll create a mall's map and I need somehow to track changes of user's location. Because of navigation in building, GPS is not a solution (low signal). So, I assume there is a way to track location changing (1-2 meters) with another module (maybe accelerometer?). Any ideas? 
Thanks

**Update:** I cannot use any additional devices such as iBeacons or so. I only can use device on which app is running. No access to wi-fi routers or so.

**Example:** I'm standing near Apple store(point A), and now I'm going to Samsung store(point B). The app should react that I started to move from point A, and know how much meters(accuracy may be not ideal) I walk from point A and in what side I'm going (east, west, south, north).

Comment: You can use Android's Network Location Provider. See in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/strategies.html

Comment: you can use WiFi triangulation but getting 1-2 meters accuracy is going to be pretty difficult and you also need WiFi obviously

Comment: The addidianal devices are mounted in the shop for which you write the app, not at the phone. If you can use their wifi, you can use their ibeacons too. One ibeacon costs about 20$. (if i remeber correctly)

Answer (score 2):

iBeacons have bean invented for your task, they are low energy blue tooth devices which emits an unique ID, and If I remeber correctly, also the distance to that beacon.
iBeacons have been invented by or for Apple. So you have to search for an alternative which works on Android.
ibeacons are mounted at the walls of the shop.

**Update:**
Things you can do:

- Count foot steps using accelrometer, like apple does in an API.
- Theoretically you could use the built in compass, but practically it has to calibrated each time it is used (this is anoying, and useres will not do it).
- You can get to decimeter accuracy using magnet field analysis of the shop and the 3-d magnetic sensor of the smartphone. This works in research ([indoor navigation using magnetic fields](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5653681)) But you have to create a magnetic map of each shop to make it work.

for WLAN:
You need at least 3 different wlan routers in the shop. Usually they will only have one.
1-2 m accuracy you will not get with wlan.
(On ios it is not possible to read the wlan device ids nearby, hopefully you can do that in android)

iBeacons or similar devices mounted in the shop at strategic placesw,
are the only feasible technology which you will get to work.

Comment: thanks for advice, but it doesn't answer my question. Please, look at updated post

Comment: Count foot steps using accelrometer is a good start, thanks. I don't mark it as answered, maybe someone advice another way.

Comment: Fine, wait 2 weeks and decide later if you get a better answer. I still will suggest to look again at the iBeacons approach. It will the only one where you have a chance to be successfull. There is no company in the world how can provide a working indoor navigation. Many work on that.

Comment: I have added a topic "magnetic field navigation"

Comment: With your comment about magnetic field navigation it seems I found the excellent service (at least their demo video shows really great results). It's www.indooratlas.com

Answer (score 0):

There is an open source Android app for tracking location without GPS. It uses `TYPE_STEP_DETECTOR` sensor available from API level 19.

You can [download it from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tananaev.stepsnavigation) and source code is [available on GitHub](https://github.com/tananaev/steps-navigation).

The app is not very accurate because it uses average step length. It can be improved if we allow user to specify or calculate automatically his personal step length.